# in laravel soap give me wrong version error once in a while?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, laravel-5.1

I try to use soap and connect to wsdl file.
I don't know why 2 from 10 request send but other give me wrong version error. I defined version in call soap by

```
'soap_version'=>        SOAP_1_1,
```

wsdl start with this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

error show me like this :

```
 "message": "Wrong Version",
  "status_code": 500,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I Find why.

in my code I used old version like this :

```
$result = $this->serve()->__soapCall($functionName, $arguments);
```

---

```
protected function serve()

{

if (is_null($this->client))
{
    $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, $this->options);
}
return $this->client;
```

}

then when I change to this, solve that :

```
$sms_client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

        $result =  $sms_client->$functionName($arguments);
```